# Java Inheritance: instance of object from parent class same for 2 child classes

Tags: java, inheritance, parent-child

What I'm trying to do is instantiate an object in the parent class called "pObject" (assume the type to be protected Boolean). One child class which extends the parent class sets "object" to "true". The other child class which also extends the parent class will check to see if "object" is set to true.

Is this possible in Java?

```
public abstract class parentClassAction{

    protected Boolean pObject;
}

public class childClass1Action extends parentClassAction{

    super.pObject = true;
}  

public class childClass2Action extends parentClassAction{

    if(super.pObject!=null){
        if(super.pObject == true){
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok I was trying to insert an image but that didn't work apparently. I'll set some pseudocode

Comment: Avoid pseudocode -- show real code please. Also, is the field static or non-static? Your question as written is a bit unclear -- please explain more as well. Let's avoid having to painfully extract information from you.

Comment: So you have class `Root` and *two* classes `Child1 extends Root` and `Child2 extends Root`? These two classes don't know nothing about each other. If an instance of `Child1` sets `pObject` this has no effect whatsoever of an instance of `Child2` (or another instance of `Child1`).

Comment: You will need to have some sort of reference to `Child1` from `Child2`, otherwise you can't really figure out if some object has been initialized or not. Or, you could use some sort of event / observer pattern.

Comment: I made edits to my question

Comment: I am suspecting an XY Problem here where you may be asking how to solve a specific code problem when the solution to the underlying issue is completely different. I may be wrong, but you may wish to post more information about the issue that is driving this question. I say this because I look at your code and scratch my head and think, 1) why would anyone want this? and 2) why is he mis-using inheritance in this way. Your issue does not seem to be one that should even involve inheritance.

Comment: I'm trying to set the parent object in child class 1 and that value will be visible in child class 2

Comment: Again, this is a misuse of inheritance and is not what inheritance is for. Instance field states are unique to the object that holds them. Again, you may wish to tell us the meta issues that are driving this, **not** how you're trying to solve this (which is wrong).

Comment: I think it is a misuse also Hovercraft, I was just wondering if there is a workaround though. In my application the admin can block certain types of users. Those users won't be able to log in to the application.

Comment: @develope: your current program structure is not anywhere near how you'd attack this problem. Again, it is not a problem that inheritance will or should solve

Comment: You can make pObject a singleton and have your classes have a reference to that singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2 different instances of subclasses - they do not share any state. Each of them has independent instance of pObject, so if you change one object it will not be seen in another one.

There are many ways to solve your problem. The easiest way: you can make this field pObject to be static - it will work for simple example, but this can be also serious limitation (if you want to have more than one instance of pObject).

Comment: Is there a way I can have the subclasses share the instance of pObject?

Comment: I only want one instance of pObject

Comment: Then I would go for `protected static pObject`

Comment: Unfortunately for my purposes, if I restart the application the pObject's value is lost, otherwise setting the object to static completely works. I have to find another solution which involves the ldap (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol). Nogard, duckstep, and Ian2thedv did answer the question I gave specifically so kudos to them. If I had enough reputation to upvote their answers I would.

Answer (score 2):

You can make `pObject` static and access it as `parentClassAction.pObject`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If `pObject` is static it will be shared:

```
public class Legit {

    public static abstract class A {
        protected static Boolean flag;
    }

    public static class B extends A {
        public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
            super.flag = flag;
        }
    }

    public static class C extends A {
        public boolean getFlag() {
            return super.flag;
        }
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();

        b.setFlag(true);
        System.out.println(c.getFlag());
        b.setFlag(false);
        System.out.println(c.getFlag());
    }
}
```

Comment: If `Boolean flag` cannot be declared as `static` e.g. in Multi-Thread scenario or maybe because of other reason, is there any way to share the value of `flag` between `Class B` and `Class C` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access **non private** fields of a super class using the syntax:

```
super.myBoolean = true;
```

Note: If the field has the default visibility (absence of modifier) it is accessible only if the sub class is in the same package.

**Edited:** I add information due to the new code added to the question.
It seems that you like to check a variable from two different objects. It is possible only if that variable is static. So declare it as `protected static` in the parent class. The rest of code rest the same.

Comment: Non-`private` is not sufficient. Also default modifier does not qualify

Comment: I know how to access non private fields as shown in my question that I just edited/ Accessing non private fields was not my question